# Open WPF window in WindowsForm APP

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I added to my WindowsForm app a new WPF window called novoLogin.

After adding it, I added the system.xaml reference....debug fine.

Now I'm trying to open this new window from the existing windowsForm.

```
novoLogin nl = new novoLogin();
nl.show();
```

The compiler is giving this error:

> Error 1   'WindowsFormsApplication1.novoLogin' does not contain a
>   definition for 'show' and no extension method 'show' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.novoLogin' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You do know that C# is case sensitive, right?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This **[brief article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/07/29/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms.aspx)** explains how you can achieve this.

If you find yourself in need to open a WPF Window from a WinForms program, this is one way to do it (works for me):

1. Create/Add a new project of type `WPF Custom Control Library`
2. Add a new Item of type `Window (WPF)`
3. Do your thing with the WPF Window
4. From your WinForms app, create and open the WPF Window

   ```
   using System;  
   using System.Windows.Forms;  
   using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;  

   var wpfwindow = new WPFWindow.Window1(); 
   ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow); 
   wpfwindow.Show();
   ```

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: I saw you added the code (and why you did this in the revision). Thanks for this, now I can keep this in mind for future answers! :)

Comment: "Do your thing with the WPF Window" Is this the thing that actually makes it work?

Comment: @Paul McCarthy No, the code in point 4 is the code that makes it work. "Do your thing" is meant as "design your WPF form". Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look to this: http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=1537&lang=en

Summary:

> Open the project’s manifest file (the one with the .csproj or .vbproj extension) in any text editor.
>   The top node  usually contains several  tags, one for each build configuration and a global one. In the global
>    node (the one without Condition attribute), search for
>   the  sub-node or **create one if it does not
>   exist**. This node should contain two GUIDs:
>   FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC, which stands for a C# project,
>   and 60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548 which stands for WPF. The
>   full line should look as follows:
>
> `<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`
>
> (If you’re interested in details, codeproject holds a complete list of
>   potential project GUIDs:
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)
>
> Reload the project in Visual Studio, and open the Add New Item wizard.
>
> Since the project is now officially classified as WPF project, this
>   wizard should now contain the WPF window option. By the way, since
>   there is no WinForms project GUID that could be overwritten, this
>   approach does not harm the existing project components.

I just tried this approach for a VB.NET project and it works!

Using VB.NET obviously you have to edit above lines substituting the GUID from {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC} to  {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to show wpf form in windowForm and there was some resource problem...

(because I used resources..). Finally I used this code in my windowsForm project:

First create a global instance of your app class like this :

```
WPFTest.App app;
```

why this is global?

because this class is singleton and you can not create more than one instance in the same AppDomain

Now for example you have a button event to show wpf form. At the button event we have :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
        {
            app = new WPFTest.App()
            {
                ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
            };
            app.InitializeComponent();
        }
        else
        {
            app = (WPFTest.App)System.Windows.Application.Current;
            app.MainWindow = new WPFTest.YourWindow();
            System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(app.MainWindow);
            app.MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

note : WPFTest is name of your project and  YourWindow() is window that you wanna to show