# Pass a Bitmap from Project to another

Tags: c#, bitmap, project, parameter-passing

I have two projects linked to each other As it shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511382/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms-link-form-app-with-wpf-app). Let's say ProjectTwo Linked to ProjectOne.

I want to pass an image that ProjectOne owned .I create a static method to pass it:

```
static Bitmap passed;
public static Bitmap PanoImageReturn()
    {
        return passed;
    }
```

& the ProjectTwo:

```
Bitmap value = ProjectOne.SimpleViewer.PanoImageReturn()
```

but this is totally wrong! What shall I do?!
I can save it & upload it but this would ruined my idea.

Comment: "but this is totally wrong!" Huh? What happens?

Comment: the most famous red line ever :p, failed to build

Comment: how could u think, u can access a variable in another project !!!

Comment: @ashok_damani: By using a public class from a referenced assembly.

Comment: You probably want to update your question with the error message

Comment: @Joanna: **What error do you get**?

Comment: @ ashok_damani I was able to link them using there windows which each one have , So, I think it might be possible to do that too, right?!

Comment: @  SLaks : The name "ProjectOne" doesn't exist in  the current context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a project reference to Project1 in Project2.
(and make sure the class is public)

Comment: I've added it before. But once I check if its exist or not I haven't found It. So I add it again but When I press Ok an error message appeared(A reference to "ProjectOne" could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency 
).

Comment: Yeah I forget something. Both are public & "SimpleViewer" refer to a window. could that cause the whole story?!

Comment: @Joanna: No; the problem is clearly explained by the error you just quoted.  You can't have a circular dependency.  Delete the reference in the other direction.

Comment: you mean the reference in ProjectOne  ?!

Comment: won't that prevent me from accessing ProjectTwo?! 'cause there is a Form parameters in ProjectOne is linking a form existed in ProjectTwo.

Comment: @Joanna: You can't have  references in both directions.  Consider making a third Common library

Comment: It doesn't work either, That's OK at least I learned anew thing. Many Thanks:).

Comment: @Joanna you made a ProjectThree that contained the stuff you wanted to share, referenced it in ProjectOne and ProjectTwo ( `using ProjectThree;` ), and it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yeah, I do. It gives me the same error of circular dependency.

Comment: @Joanna not sure what other references you still have, but are you certain that Projects 1 and 2 are not both referencing each other, and that 3 is not referencing 1 and 2?

Comment: Honestly, I have 3 Projects linked to each other, ProjectOne is the main window, both of the other two linked to. But neither two or three linked to each other. Now I have create a new WPF Custom Control Library name it PassParameter & link it to projectOne. But when I want to link passParameter to ProjectTwo, the circular dependency alert appear. I don't know if the different of the Form & WPF could cause this.