# Handling a WinForms button's Click event from a separate WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, wcf

Summary: So I have two applications: one is WinForms and the other is WPF.  I am trying to figure out how to click a button in the WinForms app and have the WPF app respond to that click.

So to get more detailed, I am working on an existing WinForms application, adding new features.  For one of those features, I needed to create a separate WPF application with an InkCanvas that sits on top of the WinForms application and allows the user to draw over the WinForms app.

I have 3 buttons on the WinForms app that are meant to control the InkCanvas: one to enable drawing, one to enable erasing, and one to clear the canvas.  What I need to figure out is how to handle those 3 buttons' Click events in the WPF application.

I've been looking at things like PRISM's EventAggregator (although I don't know if that would work between separate processes) and WCF.  WCF seems like what I should be using, but I have no experience using it, so it is slow going.  I have come across articles about WCF Duplex Services ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service))([link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF))

So I guess my question is: what is the best approach to handling a WinForms button's Click event in a separate WPF application?  Apologies in advance if this question has already been asked or if it is too vague.

Comment: Why not just use the WPF control directly in the WinForms application? You can host WPF controls using the `ElementHost` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control...

Comment: I have tried doing that.  In a nutshell, transparency is the reason I have been unable to get that to work.

Basically, whenever I try to make the background of the ElementHost transparent, it carves out a hole in the 3D scene that is being rendered in the WinForms application.  I have been unable to figure out how to prevent that from happening.  I had posted a question about that exact problem here a few weeks ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508405/drawing-over-a-3d-rendered-scene-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Have you tried using an entire WPF Window? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311956/open-wpf-window-in-windowsform-app

Comment: Hmm, let me give that a try...  That is one thing I haven't actually tried yet.

Comment: Holy crap, that actually works...  Ugh, I feel like I've wasted DAYS trying to get WCF to work when all I needed was to use a WPF window.  Thanks so much for the assistance.  Now, what should I do with this question?  Technically, your suggestion answers my other question (which if you want to write up as an answer to the question I linked above, that would be awesome).

Comment: Glad it worked, will add it as an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForms can host WPF elements using the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control, built into the Winforms control library. If that doesn't work in this case (because you are using transparency), you can try using a new WPF window that you overlay on top of the application (see [Open WPF window in WindowsForm APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311956/open-wpf-window-in-windowsform-app)).

This way you can wire up event handlers and communication without having to worry about IPC methods or managing application lifetimes between two different executables.