# Application.Current.Shutdown(); is defined in an assembly not referenced

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting the error:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IQueryAmbient' is defined in
>   an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

When doing the following:

```
public void ExitApplication()
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

The project is targeted to .NET 4.0, my Visual Studio is 2010, I tried adding

`using System.Windows.Markup;` with no succes, and

`using System.Xaml;` where Xaml doesn't exist in namespace System.

What should I do  to fix this?

Comment: If you comment `ExitApplication()` you don't have this issue?

Comment: See [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588794.aspx). It's located in PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll) C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: @DHN true, my application works fine. But if I close the application, background threads continue to run so it's never really closed. That's why I'm trying to use this.

Comment: Important lesson that `using` directives and references are completely separate concepts.

Comment: Agreed, even if they are pretty standard Windows components.

Comment: Background threads always die when you exit the application normally. You obviously have some foreground threads running somewhere. Find why and how to terminate them gracefully before trying anything like `Application.Shutdown` or `Environment.Exit`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well ok, I guess your issue is solved when you add *System.Xaml.dll* as reference to your project. The interface is declared there. Here is the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.iqueryambient.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I had to add the reference. I thought this worked before so I didn't even looked at that. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Add System.Xaml.dll to project references.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a `reference` to `System.Xaml` in your main application project. `Using System.Xaml` is not needed to be in your code.